# Is it possible to create a data subset while also filtering for categorical variables?

Tags: r, subset, numeric, categorical

I have a data set at hand that I want to generate subsets from. For my first subset I only need 2 columns from the previous total data set, which both consist of categorical variables, each with several characteristic values.
However, the data subset I want to generate is supposed to capture only one characteristic of each column/variable.

I used the following command:

```
data_bamako_OV1 <- subset(data, admin1==Bamako, year==2022, select = c(year, admin1))
```

Then, the following error message popped up:

> Error in subset.default(data, admin1 == Bamako, year == 2022, select =
> c(year,  :    object 'admin1' not found

So my question is, has this error occurred, because my filter assignments are categorical instead of numeric? And if so, how can I transform these nominal categorical characteristics into nominal numeric characteristics (10 characteristics in total for admin1; 6 characteristics in total for year)?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Is your dataset really called data? (I suspect it is not.) If it is called data, it is not a data.frame (because then the error would look different). What kind of data structure is `data` then?